# question about generic sections

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, vector-bundles

For any complex vector bundle $E$ with dimension $2n$ over the even dimensions manifold $M$, do there exist 2n generic sections? (more explicitly, 2n sections $e_1,…,e_{2n}$ such that every $e_i$ intersect with the space spaned by {$e_1,…,e_{2n}$}-{$e_i$} transversely).

I try to do this by partition of unity and
embedding $E$ to a trivial bundle, but I have no idea to control a section to make it transvers to the zero section.Could anyone help me?

Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Do you know the Transversality Theorem?

Comment: The Chern classes of the bundle will give (by duality) the degeneracy loci of generic sections, i.e., where the appropriate number become linearly dependent. In particular, the Euler class or top Chern class gives the zero locus of a generic section.

Comment: @Jonas I don't know it but I search for it. This thoerem actually solves my question, thanks !